# It is possible to pass variable or method to PHP annotation in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, variables, annotations, assert

I have this definition of private method in my entity class:

```
private function getThisYear()
        {
            return date("Y");
        }
```

Is there any way to pass the method's return value to PHP annotation like this?

```
/**
 * Get bornYear
 *
 * @Assert\Range(
 *      min = 1900,
 *      max = "this.getThisYear()"
 * )
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getBornYear()
{
    return $this->BornYear;
}
```

Comment: Good idea!!! well

Comment: Yes it's possible this was possible when  Doctrine2 ORM was born and you can take a look at this info here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html by using cache reader ...

Comment: I suggest you look at here http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Range.html#date-ranges